# Reading the Amperage of a DC Current Source using a Multimeter

Tags: dc, current-measurement, multimeter, amperage

Hello everyone this question is probably basic but i am having problems with a current source that i am trying to test:

[image: My attempt at getting the amperage]

So if memory doesn't fail me you connect the black connector to ground and the red one to positive and then i should get the amperage which in this case is in miliampers and should say 60 but i get always 0, of course the unit might be malfunctioning but i can get the voltage ok, what am i doing wrong? or the unit is to blame?

**Update 1**

I made two mistakes so far, one i had my probe on A instead of mA, and second i had the black probe on ground, now i switched it to "-", however my result is now 10mA instead of 60mA

[image]

**Update 2**

Well after much tinkering with the unit i found the problem, some of the components on the motherboard are dead, either downright broken to just not giving any reading when probed with the multimeter. So the answer is that the unit is defective. However @Tony Stewart. EE since '75 was the closest to the root of the problem so i selected his answer as right. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Looks like your red probe is in the 10 Amp socket.  If you're only expecting 60 mA, use the mA/uA socket.  You probably also havbe to move the black lead from Ground to "-" on the current source.  From the settings on the HP currrent source, I think you'll only get 6 mA, not 60.

Comment: Is the meter the only thing in the circuit? It looks like it in the photo. You may have blown the fuse in the meter unless the supply is current limited. (Although where that 60 mA is going I don't know...)

Comment: I only have the multimeter connected, i checked the fuses on the multimeter and they seem to be ok, the max output of this source is 100mA and my multimeter can hold up to 400mA or 10A, after switching ground to "-" and from A to mA i get a reading of 10mA Which is 50mA short of what i should be getting. So either i am missing part of the process or the unit is defective (the DC current source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something needs calibration.  If source is ok, check Voltage . and if wrong adjust R21 inside. If V is OK check Current shunt for overheating and replace possibly R7 and check fuses.

Fluke 83 III mA scale is good for 5% accuracy.

Comment: i can confirm that voltage reading is perfect, i will try what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You have the meter connected between the positive output and earth. The output current terminals are floating with respect to earth.

[image]

You should connect the load (a meter in this case) between the positive output and the negative output.

You can connect either of the outputs (or neither) to the earth terminal. Grounding one or the other may improve the performance in some cases.

You also need to use the mA terminal on the meter to get resolution with such a low current, and in this case the reading should be 6mA (not 60) because of the multiplier switch (10mA full scale).

You can find a copy of the manual, with corrections [here](http://neurophysics.ucsd.edu/Manuals/Hewlett%20Packard/Current%20Source%20Model%206186c.pdf)

Edit: The photo has been modified and therefore the above comments may not seem to make sense. Since you are still having problems, I **strongly** suggest you read the manual I linked above thoroughly. One obvious possible source of problems would be if the strapping was not as below:

[image]

In particular, note that the voltage limit light should have been on in the first photo but it did not appear to be on. If all else fails, it's possible that very old instrument may have some problem, but you should make sure you are using as designed.

Comment: Question updated, this feels so basic and i still feel that i am doing something wrong, thanks for the patience.